# Recommendation for Google Cloud Storage for application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have developed an application using Cloud ML Engine that recognizes images  from uploaded images. I want to test the application and allow specific people to upload images for the next 24 hours. Not all users have a Google Account. How should you have users upload images?

Have users upload the images to Cloud Storage. Protect the bucket with a password that expires after 24 hours

OR

Have users upload the images to Cloud Storage using a signed URL that expires after 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

The best option will be to [generate signed url for file upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) that expires.

You can check [example in python](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#configure-cors-bucket) how to do it or [example server side app in node.js](https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/google-cloud-signedurl-test-case)

It is also important to Configure [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#configure-cors-bucket) for the bucket, that will be used to upload.